# Caeser's Cipher not working for lower case characters

Tags: c++

Please someone run it , It runs fine for all uppercase values but if you include some x y or z the code breaks.
I found this in hackerrack and several test cases were passed but several failed.

````cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string caesarCipher(string, int);
int main() {
    string s;
    int places, length;
    cin>>length;
    cin>>s;
    cin>>places;
    if(places >26) {
        places = places % 26 ;
    }
    s= caesarCipher(s,places);
    cout<<s;
}
string caesarCipher(string S, int k){
    for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++){
        if(S[i]>='a' && S[i] <='z'){
            S[i] = S[i]+k;
            if(S[i]>'z'){
                S[i]=S[i]-'z'+'a'-1;
            }
        }
        else if(S[i]>='A' && S[i] <= 'Z'){
            S[i] = S[i]+k;
            if(S[i]>'Z'){
                S[i]= S[i]-'Z'+'A'-1;
            }
        }
        else
        ;
    }
    return S;
}```
````

Comment: Thanks for informing us that your code is not working. But what's your actual question? Did you use a debugger? Did you try to use a rubber ducky?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates for suitable hardcoded input.

Comment: You might want to learn about the [standard character classification and conversion functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte).

Comment: You chose not to provide suitable hardcoded input. So please state which input demonstrates your problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of `length` in the input? It seems ignored. I tried with "Helloxyz" as input and 2 as key. It seems to work, getting "Jgnnqzab" as ouput which seems correct. So, for what input do you get what output and what output would you expect instead?

Comment: Try this, just type in z or x or y , and shift the alphabet by 7 or 8 or 9 we get the wrong answer, only in case of lower case letter works fine for upper case letters.

Comment: Try this as input Pz-/aI/J`EvfthGH and shift by 66 places. You will see why I am so bothered. The letters near the end of alphabet are all messed up in ciphering.

Comment: Please don't bother about length you can ignore it for the time being.

Comment: I have got the answer.... I will explain it....the short explaination is char is 8 bit in c++ with value of z as 122 and the char is signed. this means that first bit is reserved for sign and only seven bits are to put in the value , 7 bit can max store upto 128 once the no goes beyond it, the code breaks.

Answer (score 1):

To my own surprise, it looks like strings do not like certain values, not even temporarily.
If you use
`S[i] = (S[i]-'a'+k)%26+'a';` instead of
`S[i] = S[i]+k;`, no value outside of a-z is ever written to the string, which as far as I tested avoids your problem.

An input of "Helloxyz" with a shift of 2 gets an output of "Jgnnqzab".
An the reverse, with a shift of 24 gets "Helloxyz" again.

With that, you do not need

```
if(places >26) {
    places = places % 26 ;
}
/* ... */
if(S[i]>'z'){
    S[i]=S[i]-'z'+'a'-1;
}
/* ... */
if(S[i]>'Z'){
    S[i]= S[i]-'Z'+'A'-1;
}
```

Comment: I Use if after addding the shift, not before it

Comment: I have got the answer.... it's a bit computer science related.... I will explain it....the short explaination is char is 8 bit in c++ with value of z as 122 and the char is signed. this means that first bit is reserved for sign and only seven bits are to put in the value , 7 bit can max store upto 128 once the no goes beyond it, the code breaks.

Comment: Now that you know that, can you edit your question so that the info needed to more easily arrive at that is in the question? I will happily help you to improve your question so that it gets reopened. Then you can create your own answer. The solution for avoiding the problem is in my answer, the explanation in yours. Together they make an insightful Q/A pair (trio). For that however, you need to spend some work on the question.

Comment: For your answer you would need to go a bit further into computer science and discuss the options for representing characters. Signed, unsigned, unicode for encoding. Also, the effect is probably an edge/special case handling. The string implementation could implement differently than what you (we) observe.